# With SDK style csproj, are Hintpath now required for assemblies in the output folder?

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, csproj

I'm hitting an issue where it seems the new CSProj files are not working well with some of our build processes. It seems that Hintpaths are now required for references that would be in the build output folder. I don't want to use hintpaths (and we haven't in the past) as local paths mess up on the TFS build servers but generally this hasn't been an issue. There are external files that get dumped into a shared output bin folder (or folders, there are Debug and release subfolders) and those files get picked up just fine during build without a hint path.

Since updating the projects to use SDK-style projects, I can get it to build locally with hintpaths that point back to the DLL in my output folder, but this fails to resolve references on the TFS server. If I remove the hintpaths, it fails locally too with error MSB3245 "Can't resolve assembly...". A quick sample I put together does build but the yellow triangle is present on the reference indicating it can't be resolved.

Has something changed where assemblies in the output folder now need hintpaths???

[Image showing csproj configuration and triangle on asembly reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzkIO.png)

Comment: Have you tried clean the build? Is the reference produced from other project? How about using project reference? It seems your issue is not related to TFS/Azure DevOps.

Comment: Have you tried clean the build? Yes, i jave tried clean build
 Is the reference produced from other project? I should have excluded rather than unloanded the other project - i did use the other project to create the other assembly, but this is a sample only and it is assembly reference i see an issue with, not project reference. 
It seems your issue is not related to TFS/Azure DevOps: Why do you say it's unrelated - As i said, the sample does build locally despite the yellow triangle, but does not in TFS.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490415/reference-gac-assemblies-in-new-csproj-format). Simply put: add the following snippet to your project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AssemblySearchPaths>$(AssemblySearchPaths);{GAC}</AssemblySearchPaths>
</PropertyGroup>
```