# References in new SDK-Style project format require hint path?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, .net-4.8

Conditions

- I am trying to migrate from the old project format to the new SDK-style .csproj format. See e.g. https://netexplorer.hashnode.dev/migrating-to-an-sdk-style-project
- .NetFramework 4.8 projects
- I have references, that are not NuGet Packages, not in GAC and not my projects
- In my current case, the pre-installed UFT Developer SDK
- My assumption is, that my issue is unrelated to UFT Developer SDK and that it could be any dependency installed anywhere. Except GAC and NuGet Packages, found by msbuild

Old style format .csproj code

```
  <Reference Include="HP.LFT.Report" />
```

New style format .csproj code (works with absolute and relative paths)

```
<Reference Include="HP.LFT.Report">
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\UFT Developer\SDK\DotNet\HP.LFT.Report.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Why do I need to add the hintPath in the new format? This is a disadvantage, because this path may change over time or from machine to machine. In the old format, somehow msbuild knew how to find my references. Is there another way to tell msbuild how to find these dependencies?

I know that msbuild's search mechanism can lead to wrong build results when it searches for "NewtonsoftJson.dll" basically anywhere. But what is the proper way to add references like this in the new format?

I found an old post with a slightly related issue. I am not sure if years later that is still the proposed solution: [Reference GAC assemblies in new CSPROJ format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490415/reference-gac-assemblies-in-new-csproj-format)

Comment: Saw you have posted the same question simultaneously. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77343653/8017690

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference GAC assemblies in new CSPROJ format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490415/reference-gac-assemblies-in-new-csproj-format)

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how that happened. I wanted to edit my questions. I don't I pressed  "post" twice, but well I guess I did somehow.

Comment: There is a [`FrameworkReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#frameworkreference) for .NET shared frameworks -- which addresses part of the old question but doesn't help with third party SDKs that are not provided as NuGet packages. Either provide the `HintPath` 
 or add to the `AssemblySearchPaths`. But create a property for the SDK path so it can be overridden when needed - e.g. `<UFTHome Condition="''$(UFTHome) == ''">some-default-path</UFTHome >`

Comment: _"not in GAC"_ Are you sure?

Comment: @shingo no entry found with `gacutil -l`

Comment: @JonathanDodds: sounds like a good option to only add my path to `AssemblySearchPaths`. I will try that.

Comment: @JonathanDodds: I am struggling to set default value centrally and re-use it in all .csproj files. Any tips?
    ```<PropertyGroup>
    <UftDeveloperPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro Focus\UFT Developer\SDK\DotNet\</UftDeveloperPath>
    <AssemblySearchPaths>$(AssemblySearchPaths);$(UftDeveloperPath)</AssemblySearchPaths>
  </PropertyGroup>```  UftDeveloperPath seems to be accessible in only one .csproj.

Comment: Each project is separate. Properties and Items don't persist across projects. You must define the `UftDeveloperPath` in each project. You can share MSBuild code across projects. Create a custom .props file and [`Import`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2022) the file. Or create a file named [`Directory.Build.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-by-directory?view=vs-2022) and place it in a parent folder of all the projects. MSBuild will search up the directories and automatically import the file.

Comment: @JonathanDodds `Directory.Build.props` is a great suggestion. When I add `UftDeveloperPath` there, that part works, but .netFramework 4.8 references from GAC cannot be found by VS. If I add `{GAC}` as well, my NuGet Packages references cannot be found.

Comment: SDK style projects don't support using a GAC

Comment: What I don't understand is: Why do all my regular .netFramework 4.8 references such as `System.ServiceProcess` or `System.Windows.Forms` break, when I modify my `AssemblySearchPaths` inside the `Directory.Build.Props`? They don't break if I modify via every .csproj file.

Answer (score 0):

By default, .NET will look in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and the project's output directory for assemblies.

The official document:

[Global Assembly Cache (GAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac)

[image]

Check whether your package is there.

But in new sdk style this feature be droped.

You can consider the way which suit your situation well based on this:

[ResolveAssemblyReference.SearchPaths Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.tasks.resolveassemblyreference.searchpaths?view=msbuild-17-netcore)

After all only these seven type can be provided.